# Webpack runtime bundling with existing bundle

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-2

Their already is bundle which is served to client. Now on hitting a server i got another bablifyed js file but i need to bundle that one with existing bundle so that all requires use that bundle webpack id instead of having their own.